# Choose I and D cache size for a MIPS program

Tags: assembly, caching, memory, mips, cpu-cache

I have written a MIPS program that has a total of 36 instructions. I think it's most suitable to choose a I-cache size with 32 words because all the instructions can be cached.

I don't understand how I would choose the D-cache, should I count how many times I read or write from/to memory?

Comment: Each MIPS instruction takes a whole word, so a 32-word cache wouldn't hold all of a 36-instruction program.  But if some of the instructions only run once at the start/end, the "hot" parts of the code might fit in a 32-word cache.  (As long as you align your instructions carefully.)  But 32 words is tiny, only 128 bytes.  Real [MIPS R2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R2000_(microprocessor)) had external SRAM I and D caches (but internal tags/controller), I think sufficient to control 64 KiB I-cache, 32 KiB D-cache.  Although real systems may have used smaller caches.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the raw count of reads / writes, but rather the size of the data memory that is accessed for each algorithmic portion of the program (the sections of the code where it spends its time).

Nominally, holding the whole program's data set in the cache is good, but if the algorithms in the program work on smaller portions of the data set at a time, called a [working set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set), a smaller cache will still work well.

The notion of working set can apply to each level of a cache in multilevel cache designs as well as to virtual memory paging.

Writing algorithms that minimize working set sizes is an entire subject matter, whether targeting some specific cache sizes/hierarchies or more broadly, called [cache oblivious algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm).

However, most programs vary their behaviors (time & memory) based on input data.  The same program supplied with small input data set vs. large input data set will generally have very differing cache requirements.

So, to really know what cache size you'll need, you need to understand the data, which may go to understanding the program input.

Comment: The term of art for how much data a program touches regularly is "working set".  (Or specifically, how many cache lines or pages, since regular access to one byte in a cache line the whole line part of your working set.)